# Adding attribute in JQuery using other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, attr

Using jQuery, how can I add an attribute into a URL using the URL other attributes?

For example, we have these URLs:

```
<a class="someclass" data-a="X">
<a class="someclass" data-a="Y">
```

Then add the following attributes using the existing one:

```
<a class="someclass" data-a="X" data-b="string1+data-a" data-c="string2+data-b">
<a class="someclass" data-a="Y" data-b="string1+data-a" data-c="string2+data-b">
```

Please note, more than one URL has the same class="someclass".

Comment: You should be using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: `attr-a` is an invalid HTML5 attribute, just like `ng-*` and others. Use `data-a` `data-b` etc

Comment: In jQuery it's simple as googling for *"jQuery data attribute"* and look like `$("[data-a]").data({b: \`${string1}${x}\`, c: \`${string2}${string1}${Y}\`})`

Comment: Even after your edit `attribute-*` is still an invalid HTML5 attribute. Use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Sure. But, this is just an example.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `data-b` - since it's not defined at initialization. And what do you mean by saying *"into a URL"*?

Comment: What are the values of `string1` and `string2`?

Comment: Just some constant word.

Comment: So by the usage of `+` in the example are you saying you want to concatentate the strings?

Comment: What are `string2` and `data-b`?

Comment: @Taplar yes, want to concatentate some strings as well as other data attributes value.

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings in JavaScript? Have you researched how to use jQuery.data() ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to derrive the other data attributes, you can loop over them and set the attributes.  If your logic is using `data()` to read the value later on, you would want to use `data()` to also set them, rather than `attr()` that I am using in the example below.

```js
$('.someclass').each(function(_, element){
  const $element = $(element);
  const a = $element.data('a');
  const b = 'string1'+ a;
  const c = 'string2'+ b;
  
  $element.attr('data-b', b);
  $element.attr('data-c', c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="someclass" data-a="X">X</a>
<a class="someclass" data-a="Y">Y</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Taplar, I don't want to read the value later. So, I think attr() should be fine. So, how can I loop it to apply the same function to the second, third,.. Anchor Element with the same class?

Comment: What do you mean?  It's already looping over all the elements with the same class

Comment: Sorry, got my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: If it solve your problem please mark this answer as correct. So it will help others users too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use data-a, data-b instead of attribute-a, attribute-b.

```
<a class="someclass" data-a="X">
<a class="someclass" data-a="Y">
```

With jquery you can get the element using:

```
var element = $('a[data-a="X"]');
```

Add new data attribute:

```
element.data('b', 'string1'+element.data('a'));
```

Get the new data attribute

```
alert('Test: ' +element.data('b'));
```

You can see it working on: https://jsfiddle.net/aw4es259/